# CSS Help - 3 column, 2 fluid, 1 fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something that should be rather basic in CSS but I'm running in circles.

I have three divs in one fluid-width div. The two on the right have undefined width and should take up 100% of their allowed space. The full div already is fluid. And the far right div should have a width of 200px and that is fixed. Sort of like this:

```
[ [fluid(label)] [fluid(textbox)] [fixed=200(div)] ]
```

I'm trying to find a way to do this in CSS.

Thanks in advance...

edit:
Here's the html

```
<footer>
    <form method="POST" action="/" id="input">
        <label for="message" form="input" class="username">Will:</label>
        <textarea id="message" cols="0" rows="0" autofocus form="input" wrap="hard" name="message"></textarea>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button type="submit" form="input" class="button medium" name="send" value="Send">Send
            </button>
            <button type="button" form="input" class="button medium" name="extras" value="Extras"><span>Extras</span><span>^</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</footer>
```

Comment: So what does your html look like?

Comment: edited the original with the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using display:table-cell - but you'll need an extra div around the textarea:

http://jsfiddle.net/tU6w2/

(though i should add this won't work in IE7 - it doesn't support table-cell)

EDIT

in answer to the additional comments, another try - this time with jQuery - i don't think it can be done in CSS only:

http://jsfiddle.net/tU6w2/1/

Comment: close. I'd like the textarea to be able to be manipulated in the center without effect the buttons AND, the left div, should be padding 20px left and right around the text, not just a fluid width, if that makes sense. The fluid part is the length of the text.

Comment: mhm. makes sense, but what you want is a lot :-) 1/ text-area manipulation: as far a i know there's no way to control that, i've seen many solid css designs that break when you scale the textarea, i prefer to add resize: none; to textareas, and 2/ i have no idea how to achieve that...

Comment: ow, you even want more.. :-) my solution won't work, in that case - it's IE8+

Comment: I'm glad to see It wasn't as trivial as I thought it was, because that made me feel stupid. I'll go with the jquery version, thanks for your help!